Which Data Type should I use for Handling an ERP: BigDecimal or Double in Java?
I am currently developing an ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning) system and need to make decisions regarding the type of data to use for handling calculations and other numerical values within the application.
I know that Java offers several options for handling decimal numbers, such as BigDecimal and Double. I understand that each has its own advantages and disadvantages, but I want to ensure that I choose the most appropriate one to maintain precision and efficiency in my system.
Here are some specific contexts where I need to apply calculations:

Billing and Payments: handle prices, taxes, discounts, etc.
Payroll and Accounting:
Inventory Management: Including unit prices and product costs.

I am inclined to use BigDecimal for financial operations due to the precision it offers, but I am concerned about the impact on performance. On the other hand, Double might be more efficient in terms of speed but could introduce rounding errors.
What recommendations do you have for handling these cases in an ERP? In which situations would it be preferable to use BigDecimal and when Double? Are there any patterns or best practices I should follow?

You should use BigDecimal for all monetary calculations.

Also do everything you can to abstract all the money arithmetic behind an internal API implemented all in one place, so that it's comparatively easy to plug in a different kind of arithmetic if needed, not to mention improve testing, support auditing, and other benefits.

The canonical question and answers: Is floating point math broken?

Double is not for decimal numbers, it is for floating point numbers.

Avoid floating-point for money
Floating-point technology trades away accuracy for speed of execution.
In Java, the primitive types float and double are floating point types. So are their wrapper classes, Float and Double. Never use these where accuracy matters. That means never for money.
Use either BigDecimal or whole integers
Instead, fractional money amounts must be handled in one of these approaches:

Use BigDecimal objects. This type is much slower than floating-point, but accurate. The syntax is clumsier than numeric literals, of course. But on the up-side, besides accuracy, you get handy methods such as Banker’s Rounding.
Move the decimal point by multiplication to get a whole number. For example, to track USD to the penny, multiply by 100 to get cents (¢) as whole integer values (long). To track USD to the tenth of a cent, multiply by a thousand to represent mills (₥).
Use a library with classes that represent money. One such library is Joda-Money, another is JavaMoney. Adding such a framework to Java itself has been considered, and may be considered again.

Table of types for fractional money



Type
Example
Notes
Pros
Cons




Floating-pointfloat & double
1.23d
Never use for money
Fast execution. Convenient use as literals.
Inaccurate.


BigDecimal
new BigDecimal( "1.23" )
Accurately represents fractional amounts.
Handy methods, such as Banker’s Rounding.
Slow. Clumsy syntax.


Whole integerint & long
long cents = new Double( 1.23d * 100 ).longValue() ;
Requires that you multiply fractional inputs, and divide to get fractional outputs.
Fast execution. Simple type, with direct matching types in database.
May be confusing to naïve programmer & user. (Be sure to label clearly and consistently such as cents or mills.)


Joda-Money library
Money money = Money.parse("USD 23.87") ;
Explicitly built for the problem of handling money amounts and math.
Handles both fixed-precision and variable-precision
Not standardized.




BigDecimal also has the Pro of allowing almost infinite great numbers (and still being accurate)

What about quantities, like stock quantity where you can have it measured in pounds?

For all kinds of money-related calculations, it would be careless not to use BigDecimal. Please use BigDecimal for all your calculations.
What happens if you don't do it? The inaccurate precision of double/Double can lead to simply wrong results when performing any kind of mathematical operation. Wrong results can cost your company money, credibility, and time to correct wrong calculations.
Performance will most likely not be an issue. Only tackle performance issues when they arise and don't pre-optimize for a problem that does not exist.

Why BigDecimal and not long?  If it's necessary to divide $10.00 among three people as fairly as possible, they won't each get $3.33 nor $3.333333; instead, two will get $3.33 and one will get $3.34.  Nothing beyond penny precision is needed to compute the proper subdivision, and no level of precision will yield the correct subdivision if one can't accommodate the penny residual.

Okey, thanks! In terms of performance, is it really that big of a difference?

See @supercat's comment - 'just use BigDecimal' is oversimplified, and rarely correct. 'just use long' is usually correct (BigDecimal is sometimes needed. But not often). You must always consider dividing, and BD won't save you there (BD can't divide 1 euro by 3 people any more than you can do that) - and you must always consider that the vast, vast majority of links to other systems that involve finance cannot convey anything smaller than the atomic unit (you cannot transfer half a cent between bank accounts, for example. So if your system can represent them.. now what?)

@rzwitserloot: COBOL has a bad reputation, but its handling of fixed decimal types had some definite advantages even though nowadays one would want to store such things as power-of-ten-scaled long integers rather than as a sequence of base-ten digits.

@supercat It's slow as molasses, doesn't solve the 'divide by 3' issue, kicks the can down the road (okay, so, we have decided, apparently, that granularity of 1 cent is not precise enough. But COBOL is not infinitely precise in any way, it just lets you define the granularity. Point is, you are still rounding. Which one is it? If rounding is at some point acceptable, why not round at 1 cent, and round intentionally? It's what the vast majority of financial systems already do. If rounding is not acceptable, cobol's solution is useless).

@supercat BigDecimal is barely better. It can't divide by 3 either, but, instead of rounding, it can throw. Which is.. not what you want either. It's a guard against developer mistakes which is nice enough, but, here's the key point: In financial systems, rounding is gonna happen and it has to be a conscious, explicit act. Want to send 8 cents to 3 people? Then 2 people get 3 cents, and 1 person gets 2, with the unlucky person chosen randomly. Or, everybody gets 2 cents, and the bank keeps 2 because the bank rounds in its favour. You can't use BD to do this. It's custom per operation.

@rzwitserloot: COBOL implements fixed-decimal types as a sequence of decimal digits, thus receiving no benefit from machines' ability to process wider integer types; that aspect of representation is obviously outdated.  COBOL does solve the "divide by three" problem, however; I think the syntax is something like "DIVIDE N BY D WITH QUOTIENT Q AND REMAINDER R".  A bit wordy, but there's no rounding involved.

@supercat This doesn't 'help'. What folks are looking for is 'simply' that you can use a data type such that you can do whatever you want with numbers without ever having to grapple with the fact that rounding errors exist. After all, if you don't mind dealing with the potential for rounding errors as they happen, you can just use long eurocents;. However, BD doesn't actually do that, nor does cobol's 'shunt the remainder over here'. That's just as easily replicated in java.
